# How to notify commits in Jenkins using TFS?

Tags: jenkins, tfs, continuous-integration

I´m looking for a way to run builds automatically in Jenkins when a commit was performed, like a git hook. Meanwhile I´m using polling, but it delays and is not smart.

All the resources I found are old and/or are based on polling strategy. There is something in '16 to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your TFS Project go to settings, then Service Hooks.  There's a built in one for Jenkins:

[image]

Comment: I'll try this and let you update asap! (currently without this permission).